# Using PDFTable lib extension with zendpdf but getting issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

How to apply word wrap using zend_pdf library, I am using MyPDFTable lib as an extension for zendPdf lib.[image]

I have used following code.

```
<?php
// include auto-loader class
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

// register auto-loader
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

try {
  // set up database access parameters  
  $params = array ('host'     => '127.0.0.1',
               'username' => 'user',
               'password' => 'pass',
               'dbname'   => 'world');

  // configure adapter and query database                   
  $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
  $stmt = $db->query('SELECT Name, Code, Region FROM country LIMIT 0, 150');

  // create PDF
  $pdf = new My_Pdf_Document('example.pdf', '.');

  // create page
  $page = $pdf->createPage();

  // define font resource
  $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

  // set font
  $page->setFont($font, 24);

  // create table
  $table = new My_Pdf_Table(3);

  // iterate over record set
  // set up table content
  while ($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $row = new My_Pdf_Table_Row();
    $cols = array();
    foreach ($record as $k => $v) {
      $col = new My_Pdf_Table_Column();
      $col->setText($v);
      $cols[] = $col;      
    }
    $row->setColumns($cols);
    $row->setFont($font, 14);
    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::TOP, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::BOTTOM, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
    $row->setBorder(My_Pdf::LEFT, new Zend_Pdf_Style());
    $row->setCellPaddings(array(10,10,10,10));
    $table->addRow($row);
  }

  // add table to page
  $page->addTable($table, 0, 0);

  // add page to document
  $pdf->addPage($page);

  // save as file
  $pdf->save();
  echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';  
} catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
  die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
}
?>
```

You will find this code on http://devzone.zend.com/1776/creating-pdf-documents-with-zend-framework/ In topic "Turning The Tables".

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial talks about the same problem you faced. They have provided a custom solution also!
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-zend5/section4.html

Comment: Thanks it is quit useful but not exact solution, such that which should lie in side MyPDFTable lib.